# Acessing manually elements of array of resources returning nothing

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to access a specific position of my array of resources, that came from a query but in my console.log it doesn't appear.

```
$scope.a = [];
var resourceGet = $resource('myurl');
$scope.a = resourceGet.query(function(data){
      return data;
}, function(error){
      console.log(error);
});
console.log($scope.a[1]);
```

Nothing on the console.
But, i can show $scope.a using ng-repeat.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The data is not immediately available. During console.log($scope.a[1]), the query may not have returned the data, hence nothing is displayed in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're dealing with asynchronous data. Your `console.log` executes before the callbacks you give to `query`, at a moment when the data hasn't been loaded yet. The code you wrote (except the callback) is synchronous.

Edit : here's an example of simple data loading with `$http`. I suggest using `$http` for simple tasks as `$resource` is more about CRUD operations. Personnally I've never used `$resource`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrqbxj?editors=101

Comment: Whats the best way to change/edit/access the incomming data from get requests right after the request?? Use $http?

Comment: You can change/edit/access in the block where you have 'return data' statement. Because, it is the place where the incoming data is actually available.  resourceGet.query(function(data){ $scope.a = data} , function(error){}); shoud work.